# How to parse buffer contents into quickfix list

Tags: vim

I have a couple of commands printing files and line numbers as results. For example PHPUnit:

```
$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit 
PHPUnit 9.5.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.4.3
Configuration: /home/mweimann/tmp/phpu/phpunit.xml

.F.                                                                 3 / 3 (100%)

Time: 00:00.011, Memory: 6.00 MB

There was 1 failure:

1) MW\SimpleTest::test2
Failed asserting that false is true.

/home/mweimann/tmp/phpu/src/SimpleTest.php:19

FAILURES!
Tests: 3, Assertions: 3, Failures: 1.
```

I am able to parse the file and line numbers out of it via e.g. `\/.*:\d+`.

My question now is: How can I populate the quickfix list with that, so that I can jump easily to each positon.

Comment: Possibly the `:cex[pr][!] {expr}` which can 'Create a quickfix list using the result of {expr}...' could help you, but I don't know enough about quickfix lists to be sure (I found it here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5612/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-a-command-as-the-quickfix-list-to-a-vim-server-f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to do that with `:help :cexpr` or `:help :cgetexpr`.

### Quick and dirty POC

1. Run the command and capture its output into a list:

   ```
   let raw_lines = systemlist('./vendor/bin/phpunit')
   ```

   or get the content of the current buffer:

   ```
   let raw_lines = getline(1,'$')
   ```
2. Filter out irrelevant lines:

   ```
   let relevant_lines = filter(raw_lines, { key, val -> val =~ '^\/' })
   ```
3. Add a column number to satisfy the default `:help 'errorformat':

   ```
   let adjusted_lines = map(relevant_lines, { key, val -> val . ':1' })
   ```
4. Feed the list to `:cexpr` or `:cgetexpr`:

   ```
   cgetexpr adjusted_lines
   ```

In one block:

```
let raw_lines = getline(1,'$')
let relevant_lines = filter(raw_lines, { key, val -> val =~ '^\/' })
let adjusted_lines = map(relevant_lines, { key, val -> val . ':1' })
cgetexpr adjusted_lines
```

We have our filenames and line numbers but we have lost some useful information in the process:

[image: qf]

### Can do better

1. Run the command and capture its output into a list:

   ```
   let raw_lines = systemlist('./vendor/bin/phpunit')
   ```

   or get the content of the current buffer:

   ```
   let raw_lines = getline(1,'$')
   ```
2. Filter out empty lines and irrelevant lines:

   ```
   let non_empty_lines = filter(raw_lines, { key, val -> val != '' })
   let relevant_lines = filter(non_empty_lines, { key, val -> val !~ '^\(PHPUnit\|Runtime:\|Configuration:\|\.F\.\|Time:\|There was\|There were\|FAILURES\|Tests:\)' })
   ```
3. Join the "title" and "message" lines:

   ```
   let lines_with_joined_messages = map(relevant_lines, 'v:val =~ "^\\d\\+)" ? v:val . " " . only_relevant_lines[v:key + 1] : v:val')
   ```
4. Join the "filepath" and "message" lines:

   ```
   let joined_lines = map(lines_with_joined_messages, 'v:val =~ "^\/" ? v:val . ":1 " . list_with_fusioned_messages[v:key - 2] : v:val')
   ```
5. Keep only those lines:

   ```
   let final_lines = filter(joined_lines, { key, val -> val =~ '^\/' })
   ```
6. Feed the list to `:cexpr` or `:cgetexpr`:

   ```
   cgetexpr final_lines
   ```

In one block:

```
let raw_lines = getline(1,'$')
let non_empty_lines = filter(raw_lines, { key, val -> val != '' })
let relevant_lines = filter(non_empty_lines, { key, val -> val !~ '^\(PHPUnit\|Runtime:\|Configuration:\|\.F\.\|Time:\|There was\|There were\|FAILURES\|Tests:\)' })
let lines_with_joined_messages = map(relevant_lines, 'v:val =~ "^\\d\\+)" ? v:val . " " . relevant_lines[v:key + 1] : v:val')
let joined_lines = map(lines_with_joined_messages, 'v:val =~ "^\/" ? v:val . ":1 " . lines_with_joined_messages[v:key - 2] : v:val')
let final_lines = filter(joined_lines, { key, val -> val =~ '^\/' })
cgetexpr final_lines
```

There are probably many other, smarter ways to massage that list but at least we get a nice little quickfix integration:

[image: qf]

Comment: I don't want to execute the command again. That is what `let raw_lines = systemlist('./vendor/bin/phpunit')` does. Is it possible to read the lines from the current buffer instead (as it already contains the PHPUnit output)?

Comment: Yes, see `:help getline()`.